# Is there a clean way to assign the Class of a generic type to a variable?

Tags: java, generics

Given this code:

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// Type mismatch: 
// cannot convert from Class<capture#1-of ? extends List> to Class<List<Integer>>       
Class<List<Integer>> typeTry1 = ints.getClass(); 

// Type safety: 
// Unchecked cast from Class<capture#2-of ? extends List> to Class<List<Integer>>
Class<List<Integer>> typeTry2 = (Class<List<Integer>>) ints.getClass();

// List is a raw type. References to generic type List<E> should be parameterized
Class<? extends List> typeTry3 = ints.getClass();
```

Is there a way to get the `Class` of a `List<Integer>` without an error or warning? I can suppress the warnings easily enough, but if Java requires me to suppress a warning for this valid code, I am very [disappoint](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/son-i-am-disappoint).

On the other hand, if warning suppression is the only way, what is the safest to suppress?

Comment: Apparently there is no warning free way because of erasure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens

Comment: There is really no point in using a concrete generic type for the Class object reference, because that information is not there in the object being referenced, so in my Opinion `Class<? extends List>` or `Class<? extends List<?>>` are the best types for the variable. I was surprised though that I couldn't find a warning-free cast to the wildcarded target type... However, as Class objects are mostly used for reflection anyway, you might be fine using `Class<?>`, which works without warnings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a real Catch-22 in Java.

The compiler warns you if you don't add a generic type to `List`:

```
// WARN: List is not typed
Class<? extends List> typeTry3 = ints.getClass();
```

That's because, in most cases, it's really best to type your Lists.

However, because of type erasure, there's no way for Java to figure out the generic type of `List` at runtime, and the compiler knows that.  Therefore, there is no method on `Class` that will returned a typed object:

```
// ERROR: ints.getClass() doesn't return a Class<List<Integer>>, it returns a Class<List>
Class<? extends List<? extends Integer>> var = ints.getClass();
```

So you *must* cast it to a typed list.   However, as you know, since there is no runtime type checking, Java warns you about any casts to a typed variable:

```
// WARN: Casting to typed List
Class<List<Integer>> typeTry2 = (Class<List<Integer>>) ints.getClass();
```

Any attempt to get around this is essentially a means of confusing the compiler, and will inevitably be convoluted.

Your best bet then is to go with Option B:

> On the other hand, if warning suppression is the only way, what is the safest to suppress?

The safest way to suppress this warning is to make your `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation as localized as possible.  Put them above each individual unchecked cast.  That way it's absolutely clear who's causing the warning.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this would be to create your [own class](http://ideone.com/mRUD9#view_edit_box).  I am not sure if this would meet your needs.

I am not really sure what you are trying to achieve.  So perhaps [wildcards](http://ideone.com/1I6IF) is the answer.

```
import java.util.*;

class Main
{
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            Class<?> clazz = list.getClass();
            System.out.println(clazz) ;
      }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me like a faire solution to tell the compiler: "I know that I will get a class of _something_, please give it to me without complains, even though _you_ (the compiler) may be unable to infer/keep the type of this _something_".