# Using generic method return type, list

Tags: java, class, generics, type-conversion

I am querying a rest service and trying to deserialize xml response into jaxb annotated classes. I want to use generic return type but I am unable to figure the syntax how to pass custom type list class to the method. I have following method at this point.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected <T> T getRestResponse(String path, List<String[]> params, final Class<T> type) {
    ResteasyWebTarget target = getTarget();
    target = target.path(path);
    if (params != null) {
        for (String[] s : params) {
            target = target.queryParam(s[0], s[1]);
        }
    }

    Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get();

   // This works!
   // List<GridNodeDTO> gridNodeDTOs = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<GridNodeDTO>>() {
    });
    // This does not, List is not expected: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/xml and type interface java.util.List
    return (T)response.readEntity(new GenericType(type) {});
}
```

I call it like:

```
    Class<List<GridNodeDTO>> clazz = (Class) List.class;
    // clazz is: interface java.util.List
    List<GridNodeDTO> restResponse = getRestResponse("1/abc", clazz);
```

Following does not compile:

```
    Class<List<GridNodeDTO>> cl = (Class<List<GridNodeDTO>>) new ArrayList<GridNodeDTO>().getClass();

Error:(46, 103) java: inconvertible types
  required: java.lang.Class<java.util.List<net.s.q.helper.dto.rest.GridNodeDTO>>
  found:    java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ? extends java.util.ArrayList>
```

It is working when T is not List, but single class. But I would like the method to be able to work with both, lists and single classes.

Comment: This does not work with `List` because due to type erasure, the method does not receive any information about the type of list it gets and returns a raw `List` which isn't necessarily the same type as the result you're expecting.

Comment: Does this mean that I must have separate method for `List` types and single types?

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060491/is-there-a-clean-way-to-assign-the-class-of-a-generic-type-to-a-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will compile:

```
Class<? extends List<GridNodeDTO>> cl = (Class<? extends List<GridNodeDTO>>) new ArrayList<GridNodeDTO>().getClass();
```

Or

```
Class<? extends List<GridNodeDTO>> cl = new ArrayList<GridNodeDTO>().getClass();
```

Generics is a new kettle of fish that you need to clearly understands.

If one declares, `Class<List<Dome>>`, the compiler understands the bounded type `T` as a `List<Dome>`. By unbounding it using the wildcard `?` and `extending` its type, this will work?

The Oracle documentation on [Bounded Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) will help.

Comment: `Error:(47, 113) java: inconvertible types
  required: java.lang.Class<java.util.List<helper.dto.rest.GridNodeDTO>>
  found:    java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ? extends java.util.ArrayList>`